# mysql query with Join and union all

Tags: mysql, join, sum, union

I have a union all query from 4 tables. From the 4 tables I am getting the total quantity of the `Original_APN` from all the 4 tables. For that I am using the below query.

```
SELECT Original_APN SUM(Quanity) Quanity  FROM (
  SELECT Original_APN, Quanity FROM hs_apn1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Original_APN, Quanity FROM hs_apn2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Original_APN, Quanity FROM hs_apn3
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Original_APN, Quanity FROM hs_apn4
) a
GROUP BY Original_APN LIMIT 0,4
```

Below is the out put I am getting:

```
+---------------+---------+
| Original_APN  | Quanity|
+---------------+---------+
| 0097512135344 |   30.00 |
| 0097512203272 |    2.00 |
| 0097512203296 |    2.00 |
| 0617823119019 |  200.00 |
+---------------+---------+
```

Now my requirement is I have another table prices. IN that table I have the common column Original_APN. IN prices table I have Original_APN,  aritkel, product_name, and price. Below is my desired output. But its failing to join this prices table with my above union all query.

```
+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+
| Original_APN  | Quanity | Artikel | product_name | price |
+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+
| 0097512135344 |   30.00 | 122     |    TEST1     | 11.00 |
| 0097512203272 |    2.00 |  34     |    TEST2     | 12.45 |
| 0097512203296 |    2.00 | AX1     |    TEST3     | 15.65 |
| 0617823119019 |  200.00 | MN4     |    TEST4     | 22.35 |
+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Is `Original_APN` unique in `prices` table?

Comment: What is your current code to join the union query with the second query? You can do something like `SELECT Original_APN, Quantity, Artikel, Product_name, Price FROM union_query INNER JOIN prices ON union_query.Original_APN = prices.Original_APN;`

Comment: hi Aziz, no Original_APN is not unique in prices table. sorry i forgot to mention another column aritcle number which is present in all the tables. This article number is unique in prices table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table alias and then join on prices table like this:

```
SELECT s.Original_APN, s.Quantity, p.Artikel, p.product_name, p.price FROM (
  SELECT Original_APN, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM (
    SELECT Original_APN, Quantity FROM hs_apn1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Original_APN, Quantity FROM hs_apn2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Original_APN, Quantity FROM hs_apn3
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Original_APN, Quantity FROM hs_apn4
  ) a
  GROUP BY Original_APN
) s
INNER JOIN
prices p
ON s.Original_APN = p.Original_APN
```

Comment: hi Aziz, no Original_APN is not unique in prices table. sorry i forgot to mention another column aritcle number which is present in all the tables. This article number is unique in prices table